# Need to a maven plugin to check whether the dependency artifact exists in Nexus or not

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am working on a maven project. I have a lot of dependency files which I need to check whether the specific versions of these dependency files exists in the nexus repository or not. Do we have a maven plugin which will check whether the dependency exists in nexus or not.

Comment: What kind of dependency files? In Maven you have the pom file? Why do you need to check if they exist? If you build your project it will fail if the dependency does not exist? I don't understand your problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your answer. You were right I did the same and got the solution.